# Non-ARC to ARC: Pointer to a pointer to an object (**)

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, double-pointer

I am trying to convert an iOS project into ARC.

I am using the compiler flag for some of the files.

But one of the files contains a variable declared within a method like the following:

```
aClass **obj;
```

With ARC turned off, it gives an error:

> "pointer to non-const type without explicit ownership"

I could silence the warning by doing this:

```
aClass *__strong* obj;
```

Which I believe is not a good practice as far as ownership is concerned.

But the error didn't exist in non-ARC environment.

My question is simply as follows:

How would I change from non-ARC to ARC setup the declaration of the object without having to use `*__strong*`?

i.e., how could I declare (or make changes to declaring) `aClass **obj` under ARC without have to use `*__strong*`, which I am sure I have read somewhere it is not a good practice to do but I forgot where I read it.

And:

Why didn't it give error under non-ARC environment.

Comment: Some context would be helpful. What is assigned to the variable, where/how is it used, scope, lifetime, ... ?

Comment: @MartinR It is declared within a method and is then passed to another method as parameter. It isn't written by me. I don't have the code at hand or else I could definitely post more. But my memory is valid. It is declared within a method and then passed to another method as parameter. Thanks.

Comment: The _double_ pointer is passed to another method, or the object is? Does that other method set the variable? Where is it set originally? What are you doing with it after the other method returns?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** You probably don't want a pointer to a pointer unless you can avoid it. It's pretty poor design to do so under a system where memory is managed for you. This answer explains more: [Pointer to a pointer in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482229/pointer-to-a-pointer-in-objective-c).

### More Details

Under non-ARC, the system leaves retain/release up to you so it doesn't matter who owns a pointer. You, the programmer, owns it. In ARC land, the system needs to know when to retain or release, and it can't always infer which class/object has ownership over a particular object. Other classes may need the reference but the class that declared it is done with the object already. Basically, the `__strong` tells the declaring class that it should be in charge of managing the pointer. It 'overrides' the ownership of the pointer in a way. So that's a way to get around it. The best way to get around it would be to refactor the code to not use explicitly managed memory, but how you've fixed it will work if that's not possible/too hard.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is really a poor answer, stemming, I think, from poor understanding of memory management, and when pointer to pointer is needed. Calling something you don't understand as "pretty poor design" is most likely what got you the downvote.